# Writing Haskell function to compute n-th power of a function?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, function-composition

I've been getting confused by this question for a few days now: Write a Haskell function, `power n f` which computes the *n*-th power of function *f*, i.e., *f<sup>n</sup>*, using the function composition operator.

So am I supposed to multiply the function `f` by itself `n` times? I don't understand how the composition operator has any role in this as it wouldn't be needed?

Comment: @karakfa I think it's an assignment about using recursion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of *multiplying* `f` by itself `n` times, you should *compose* `f` by itself `n` times; in other words, instead of trying to compute `f * f * ... * f`, try computing `f . f . ... . f` (using Haskell's notation of `.` for function composition).

Since your question looks like a quiz/homework you got assigned, I am not going to go into more detail just yet; hopefully the above is enough to get you started.